# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Dropdown empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have this dropdown that should contain a list of items i.e.

1. Debug
2. Information
3. Warning
4. Danger

This is how I obtain the list

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetLogLevels()
{
    var data = dbContext.EventLogs.Distinct().ToList();
    var modifiedData = data.Select(u => u.Level);
    return modifiedData;
}
```

This is my controller and viewmodel

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var levels = new SelectList(logsData.GetLogLevels(),"Level","Level");
    var llvm = new LevelsListViewModel
    {
        Levels = levels
    };
    return View(llvm);
}

public class LevelsListViewModel
{
    public SelectList Levels { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I declare it in my view

```
var level = "<div class='col-sm-3 search-spacing'><label for='Level'>Level</label><select asp-for='Level' asp-items='@Model.Levels'></select></div>";
```

The problem now is that for some reason it loads an empty list. When I debug the controller, I can see my values.

On a sidenote, is that the correct way of obtaining one field and populating the list? I want a distinct value only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in this line:

```cs
var levels = new SelectList(logsData.GetLogLevels(),"Level","Level");
```

The `GetLogLevels` method returns a collection of `string`, which does not contain a `Level` property.

There's two ways of resolving this:

- change the return type of the `GetLogLevels` method so it returns a collection of event logs which have a `Level` property; or
- use a [different contructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.selectlist.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Rendering_SelectList__ctor_System_Collections_IEnumerable_) of the `SelectList` class which only takes a collection of objects without specifying the value property name nor the text property name, like `var levels = new SelectList(logsData.GetLogLevels());`

Comment: Little trick: Use the `nameof` operator to avoid this issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This line causing problem because `GetLogLevels()` method returns `IEnumerable<string>`, which doesn't have property named `Level` in its context:

```
var levels = new SelectList(logsData.GetLogLevels(),"Level","Level");
```

There are some solutions to solve this issue:

1) Converting directly to `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

```
// Controller action
var levels = logsData.GetLogLevels().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x, Value = x }).ToList();

// Model class
public class LevelsListViewModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> Levels { get; set; }
}
```

2) Using `SelectList` overload with single parameter

```
var levels = new SelectList(logsData.GetLogLevels());
```

3) Using `ToDictionary()`

```
var levels = new SelectList(logsData.GetLogLevels().ToDictionary(), "Key", "Value");
```

**Note:** If `EventLogs` contains multiple columns, you can't use `Distinct()` on that way. You should use `GroupBy` and `Select` first distinct values:

```
var data = dbContext.EventLogs.GroupBy(x => x.Level).Select(gr => gr.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
return data;
```